# É possível aplicar estilo CSS em método de envio de e-mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho o seguinte método que envia um e-mail de recuperação de senha para o usuário.
Gostaria de saber se é possivel aplicar algum tipo de formatação CSS no mesmo, a fim de deixar mais atrativo o e-mail enviado.

E-mail Recebido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public void EnviarEmailRedefinicaoSenha(int Codigo)
        {
            try
            {
                string empresa = _config.GetValue<string>("EmpresaEmail");
                Clientes objClientes = new Clientes(_config).ConsultarClientes(Codigo);
                Data = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                this.Assunto = "Redefinição de senha";//Assunto,
                StringBuilder BodyContent = new StringBuilder();

                Link = "<a href =http://" + Link + "/Accounts/RedefinicaoSenha?id=" +
                    PCIGlobal.Encrypt(Codigo.ToString(), _config.GetValue<string>("keyEncryption")) +
                    "&T=" + PCIGlobal.Encrypt(Data, _config.GetValue<string>("keyEncryption")) +
                    ">Clique aqui</a>";

                BodyContent.Append("Prezado(a) " + objClientes.CliNome + ", ");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("Você solicitou a redefinição da sua senha de acesso ao Escritório Virtual.");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("Não se preocupe, o processo é simples, basta clicar no link abaixo e seguir as instruções.");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append(Link);
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("Qualquer problema entre em contato conosco.");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("Atenciosamente,");
                BodyContent.Append("<br/>");
                BodyContent.Append("Equipe <b>" + empresa + "</b>");



                this.Mensagem = BodyContent.ToString();
                this.EnviarEmail();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sim é possível usar o CSS direto na Tag. Qualquer folha de Estilo indexada vai ser ignorada pela maioria dos SMTP, algo tipo isso deve funcionar: `BodyContent.Append("<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">Você solicitou a redefinição da sua senha de acesso ao Escritório Virtual.</p>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Apenas para ficar como registro vou publicar o meu comentário como resposta. Assim vc pode finalizar a pergunta se achar que resolveu o seu problema.*

Sim é possível usar o CSS direto na Tag. Qualquer folha de Estilo indexada vai ser ignorada pela maioria dos SMTP, algo tipo isso deve funcionar:

`BodyContent.Append("<p style="font-size:16px; color:red;">Você solicitou a redefinição da sua senha de acesso ao Escritório Virtual.</p>");`

O código acima seria o mesmo que: `p {font-size:16px; color:red;}` no .css

Aqui tem dois links em português que pode te ajudar com boas práticas de CSS para email

https://tableless.com.br/boas-praticas-para-e-mail-marketing/  https://www.benchmarkemail.com/br/help-FAQ/answer/Usar-CSS-em-emails-HTML